# Get sensor values Ubuntu Touch

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, sensors

I'm new to Ubuntu applications and I'm trying to make an application for Ubuntu Touch that reads the values from the sensors (Accelerometer, Gyroscope,...) but I don't know where to begin. Which language to use? QML, C++.. I've done a thorough search around the web and I couldn't find a single sample application using sensors in ubuntu touch.

I've tried to use QtMobility and the QtSensors plugin with QtCreator but it only runs the code on the desktop. When I try to run the app on the device a message saying that the modules are not installed appears. So, I don't know if QtSensors is implemented in Ubuntu Touch or even if this is the right way to access sensors in Ubuntu touch.

Answer (score 0):

Because work on this is not yet done (only some). Full support will be for QML and Qt. I think you'll probably be able to also use them with other languages eventually. There was a UDS (Ubuntu Developers Summit) session about this. To Get the best answers, it might be best to subscribe on the mailing list and ask there (just send a mail to it):

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-phone